# C programming multiple definition error

Tags: c, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for C programming.

While building the program I am getting a `multiple definition of 'main'` error.

I have multiple source files in the same project, so why I am getting a `multiple definition` error, how can I avoid it?

Is it correct to have more than one source file in the same project?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
multiple definition of main'` error.
```

Tells that:
You have more than one function named `main()` defined across your multiple files.
Remove the redundant `main()` function and keep only one.
Defining multiple definitions for a function breaks the One Definition Rule and hence the error.

Comment: That I understood, I have multiple source files in each source file one main function is there, is that ok to have only one main function for multiple source files

Comment: I have only one main function in each source file, but still am getting multiple definition error

Comment: @Chaithu: Yes, You should have only one `main()` function for your project.Can you please post the files you have and their contents in the Question? I believe they must not be too much to post here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct to have multiple files in the same project.  Almost all non-trivial C projects have multiple files.  If you are getting the "multiple definitions of main" at the link time, that means the main function was defined in more than one link objects.  That can happen if

1. you actually have multiple mains defined,
2. you are linking to a library that has main defined
3. you have multiple files that #include a file with main.

   #include of a .c file is normally not what you want to do.  If you want to use functions defined in other .c files, you generally want to create header files (.h) that have [prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914589/c-prototype-functions) of the functions.

Comment: according to my understanding, I should create header file (.h) which contain #include and main function and to call them in each source file... is that right

Answer (score 0):

Check how to define and use build configurations in **Eclipse** to switch `main()` in [multiple definition of main error in eclipse using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926630/multiple-definition-of-main-error-in-eclipse-using-c/40584300#40584300)