# C prototype functions and default argument promotions in C function calls

Tags: c, prototype, function-prototypes, promotions

**EDIT:** Actually this is a duplicate for this question -
[Why does a function with no parameters (compared to the actual function definition) compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950642/why-does-a-function-with-no-parameters-compared-to-the-actual-function-definiti)

I am a beginner to C and while I understand the need of function prototypes  and the default argument promotion machinery. I also read several 
posts about this topic on SO.

1. [Default argument promotions in C function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls)
2. [C prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914589/c-prototype-functions)

I am still confused with the obtained warning and final result for this simplified snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void impl();

int main(void)
{   
    impl(3.0);
    return 0;
}

void impl(val)
{
    printf("%.2f", val);
}
```

I get the following warning: **`format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]`** for this line **`printf("%.2f", val);`**

I can not understand why it is supposed by a compiler that `val` should be treated as `int` and not to perform default argument promotion. Also I read that if you don't provide argument types:

> An ANSI C compiler will assume that you have decided to forego function prototyping, and it will not check arguments.

The result which is printed to the console is **`0.00`**, but as I understood  the caller will place double on the stack and `%f` also means double in `printf` so it reads double off the stack, and the result should not be affected. While this question [C Function with parameter without type indicator still works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202232/c-function-with-parameter-without-type-indicator-still-works) explains some bits, I still do not understand the problem to the end. Also I can't find where it is stated that the argument without a type should be treated by compiler as type `int`.

I think that I do not understand this part *6.5.2.2 "Function calls"* written in the standard:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions.

Compiled with `clang 6.0` and `--std=c89` flag under Windows 10.

Comment: You’ve declared `impl()` but it has no prototype.  You define it using an implicit `int` argument. That was allowed in C90 (for backwards compatibility) but banned in c99.  The other problems are consequences of these.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I understand that I define a function with implicit argument, but I can not find the source where it is stated that implicit argument is treated as type `int`.  Could you give me the link?

Comment: This is stated in C89 standard in  Section 3.7.1 under "Semantics" part.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
void impl(val)
```

doesn't specify the formal type of the `val` argument. This makes it default to `int`. This has nothing to do with what kind of value gets passed to the function at run-time, and would be equally true if the function was never called.

Also omitting the type is very old-school and not supported in modern C, I think.